# Datagridview and checkboxlist

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkboxlist

I have a question. Let's say i have a checkboxlist with the ingredieints for a cake and i choose not just one but more ingredients (3-4). I want to save this in datagridview. Can datagridview show more than one ingredient or is this not possible ? 
You see i'm making an application for bakeries and for ordering cakes you will choose the type of cake and adding(toppings) and the number of cakes you want. Then I would like to save this to datagridview, or show this in dgv and then when I would finish with ordering i would just click on send button in dgv and all the orders i made would be sent to an email. I hope you understand what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in its simplest uses a DataGridView is a 2-dimesional container; a 'grid', so you can have as many rows and columns as you want.

If you want to display them all in row you should first try to estimate the maximum number of ingredients. Then you add this number of columns to the target DGV.

Then add a row and fill its column cells with the ingredients.

In case you come across a cake with even more ingredients that would't be a problem either as you can always add more columns.

Empty cells are no problem, just make sure to always check for null values.

By the way, cells are quite powerful and you can have a tag for each single cell, so you can add as many data of any complexity to the cell beyond its mere value!

Here is some simple sample code:

```
    while (dataGridView1.ColumnCount < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count)
           dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "");
    int newRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    int item = 0;
    foreach ( object o in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        dataGridView1[item, newRow].Value = o.ToString();
        item ++;
    }
```

Comment: Well I have a form and i want to transfer the data i enter in here to the datagridview which is on another form. So I have 2 forms. One for entering data and saving it, and the other for datagridview in which you can see what you entered in the previous form. Do you get what i mean ?

Comment: This can be easily done. Do you want the ingredients displayed all in one row or each on a row of its own?

Comment: I want them all in one row.

Comment: Note the correction - I always confuse row=y and column=x..
Is this acceptable now?

Comment: sorry for being offline quite long. Well thank you for information, i will try to work something out.